# Formal logic and current language

Tags: logic

What is the negation (logically speaking) of the following proposition:

> *Today* I will do *this* task.

Comment: Today I will not do this task.

Comment: $\neg(Today I will do this task.)$

Comment: It is not true that I will do this task today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation can be as simple as:

"It is *not* the case that today I will do this task."

Comment: this is not what I mean. I mean, should the negation be something like "I will do this task not today or I will do another task today"?

Comment: All you know is that you will not do the task today. The negation of the statement does not imply that you will do another task today, nor that you will do the task on another day.

Comment: I see. So "I'll do this task tomorrow", "I will not do this task until tomorrow", "I will do this task in 3 or 4 days", "Today I'll complete another task", "Today I'll do another task and tomorrow this one" should all be considered negations (logically)?

Comment: The negation: "I will not do this task today" encompasses all those possibilities, including "I will never do this task."

Comment: I see. And do you think it is possible to think of the proposition as P and Q, where P = I'll do a task today; Q = I'll do this task, so that not P and Q = not P or not Q?

Comment: Sure, you can think of it like that.

Comment: What I would like to say is: if the negation of "p is an even prime" is "p is not even or p is not prime", shouldn't the only legitimate negation of "Today I'll do this task" be something of the form "I'll not do a task today or I'll not do this task"?

Comment: What you need to note is that "I will not do this task today" already includes the possibility that I will never do this task. Is it not true that "I will not do this task today" is true in the case that I never do this task?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I would like to make the negation "explicit" by enumerating all the possible cases individually.

Comment: @mathlearner Then you'll be quite busy. There's infinitely many of them. "I'll will not do this task with green eggs and ham", etc

Answer (score 1):

You simply try to make the opposite of the proposition "Today I will do this task", such as: "Today is **not** the case that I will do this task", or "Today I will **not** do this task".